# sending result from one card (Bootstrap) to other one

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Hi i have 2 card ( bootstrap ) i wanna that wen i click on Cases info i will have result some text on second card 
First Card:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="card-title">Cases Infos</h4>
        <p class="category">Parent - Child</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

second card:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <p> text text </p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("asd").addEventListener('click',showData);

function showData(){
  document.getElementById("data").innerHTML="New Data"
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <p id="asd"> Show Case</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <p id="data"> text text </p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```